# Is it possible to distinguish which part was null from stack trace?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, stack-trace

When I have a method like:

```
public class Tttttt {

    public Thing getThingBy(String name) {
      return aaa.getThingBy(name);
    }
}
```

And then I see in logs NPE

```
Caused by java.lang.NullPointerException
   at xxx.yyy.Tttttt.getThingBy(SourceFile:666)
```

And the `666` fits the method definition, then can I say whether `name` was `null` or `aaa` was `null`?

Comment: you may guess, but there is no sure shot way of knowing unless you print all variables.

Comment: @LyubomyrShaydariv, and we know because...

Comment: If `name` was `null`, you would have the `getThingBy` call in the stack trace.

Comment: @RishiGoel, there's no guessing needed.

Comment: Have you initialized aaa?

Comment: @RishiGoel That is not correct. In this case clearly it is `aaa` that was null. If it was `name`, the call to `aaa.getThingBy()` would have succeeded and would appear on the stack trace. No guessing.

Comment: @MarianPaździoch Even if they are named both the same, there would be another line in the Stacktrace if it were `name` that is null.

Comment: Calling in an objectmethod where object is null leads to a NPE (NullPointerException). Check if its instantiated somewhere with "new" or with an annotation like @Inject.

Comment: Tempted to vote as a duplicate of this.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988788/what-is-a-stack-trace-and-how-can-i-use-it-to-debug-my-application-errors

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils ... because `aaa` is the only dereferenced object + no wrapper-to-primitive unboxing here. At least I believe the line 666 code is posted.

Comment: @EJP - sorry, my bad..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case `aaa` is `null`.

`name` also can be `null` but it will be passed to the `getThingBy` as a parameter and you'd have more entries in your stack trace if the exception was thrown down there.

Answer (score 1):

> can I say whether name was null or aaa was null?

This is a poor example...  `aaa` is most certainly null. Passing a null parameter into that method doesn't throw any exception. Even if the method did call itself, you'd see that in the stacktrace.

Say it did get called again, and you used `aaa.someMethod(name.length())` on the exact same line. Then you might still be able to determine the variable based on the class type and method mentioned in the stacktrace, as for this question `at xxx.yyy.Tttttt.getThingBy` compared to `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.length()' on a null object reference`